# I need to open .html file in jmeter

Tags: java, performance, testing, jmeter

I am new in JMETER.

My source file is in my local machine: . (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/file.html)

How can I open this file in JMETER?

Comment: JMeter is for profiling applications.  The only way your question make sense is if you're profiling a web server, and ask the web server to open an html file.

Comment: But when this file will be opened. It will send a lot off information to server, and get some response. Is this just possible to open file in jmeter?

Comment: "It will send a lot off information to server" - How?  Does it use Websockets or something?

Comment: Kind off. This is secure doc from my server, and I need to check perfomance. Open a lot of files in the same time

Comment: Maybe get JMeter to run a batch file, which opens the file?

Comment: This is no exactly what I want. I mean when we want to get response from google I use HTTP Request with https://www.google.com.ua.

Comment: I need the same with file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/file.html. then I will get page where I will put my login and password and gat information that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) guide, all you need is to do is to configure [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as follows:

- Protocol: `file`
- Path: `C:/Users/user/Desktop/file.html`

  [image: JMeter HTTP Local File]